# Korean(Hangul) keyboard doesn't work properly

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus, input-language, korean

When I type in Korean it types like "ㅎㅏㄴㅏ ㄷㅜㄹ ㅅㅔㅅ ㄴㅔㅅ". So what I mean is it doesn't connect the letters.
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
**Input Source:** Korean(Hangul)
**Input method system:** IBus
**Keyboard layout:** "Dubeolsik KSX 5002" (p.s There isn't "Dubeolsik")
*Please help me :(( Thanks.*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. This issue is perhaps popular; characters are separated into consonants and vowels in some apps (telegram facebook), as long as I can find the solution is to change either 1) '3 set system(sebeolsik)' or phonic input (romaja) instead of '2 set system (debeolsik)'; 2) use fcitx-hangul; 3) upgrade to 22.04 LTS. Note: I don't speak or read Korean.